# Cannot persist object because of foreign key relationship java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities A and B - A is auto-generated by using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin and B is created by me and contains a Many To One relationship to A. The auto-generated one (A) has 4 attributes, but the table in the database which corresponds to it has an additional column called id, which is the reference column for the foreign key in the second entity(B), which is called idA.

I have to persist objects of type B in the database and I need to set the value for idA as well. Even though the value is well set, by getting it from an object of type entity A ( taken from the database ), I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class. I get the value if I have an object of type A, but if I assign it to object B, it gives me that error.

I will show the code:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2019-10-31T17:01:04.704+02:00")

public class A{

  protected Integer accountId = null;
  protected Integer range = null;
  protected Integer address = null;
  protected Integer agency = null;
  protected Long id;

@Column(
        name = "ID"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    )
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setid(Long value) {
        this.id = value;
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class B implements Serializable {

        private long id;
        private String name;
        private long idA;
        private long age;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class, cascade = {
                CascadeType.ALL
        })
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_A", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
        public long getIdA() {
            return idA;
        }

        public void setIdA(long idA) {
            this.idA= idA;
        }
```

```
EntityManager em;

List<A> entitiesList = repositoryA.findAllEntities(); // method which gets all the entries from the table

for(int i = 0; i < entitiesList.size(); i++) {
  B target = new B();
  target.setName("Andrew");
  target.setidA(entitiesList.get(i).getId()); // the value for the id is correctly taken from the database entry
  em.persist(B); ---> line which gives error because of IllegalArgumentException
```

How can I persist my object if the auto-generated class does not have a getter or setter for the column which is the foreign key ?

Comment: Are you sure the generated A class you've shown is the same one from `List<A> entitiesList`? I can't see how `target.setidA(entitiesList.get(i).getId());` would even compile.

Comment: I did not post exactly my code, I modified it a bit so that it is easier to read...everything compiles

Comment: Were you able to get this figured out? I still have a lot of questions about the setup. Did you extend A to add the `id` field? Is your extended A annotated as an Entity? Or have you setup the mapping for the generated A class in an hbm? Is it `target` that's being persisted in the line that throws the exception? Have you tried an A field on B instead of a field for A#id?